# Inserting a New UpdatableRecord and Receiving Error on Duplicate Primary Keys

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jooq

I'm trying to insert a new record using UpdatableRecords in jOOQ 3.4.2.  The pattern is extremely concise and pleasant to use, except that the `INSERT` reads null values as no value and ignores default values or a generated index.  How can I use the UpdatableRecord to do an insert that respects default values and generated indexes?

Here's my table:

```
CREATE TABLE aragorn_sys.org_person (
    org_person_id SERIAL  NOT NULL,
    first_name CHARACTER VARYING(128)  NOT NULL,
    last_name CHARACTER VARYING(128)  NOT NULL,
    created_time TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT current_timestamp  NOT NULL,
    created_by_user_id INTEGER,
    last_modified_time TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,
    last_modified_by_user_id INTEGER,
    org_id INTEGER  NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_org_person PRIMARY KEY (org_person_id)
);
```

Note my primary key and default values.  Now here's my jOOQ code:

```
// orgPerson represents a POJO filled with my values to be inserted and null for everything else
// Note that orgPerson.orgPersonId is null
OrgPersonRecord orgPersonRecord = create.newRecord( ORG_PERSON, orgPerson );
Integer orgPersonId = create.executeInsert( orgPersonRecord );
```

But when I run this, I get the error `null value in column "org_person_id" violates not-null constraint`.

I noticed the jOOQ docs say that calling `newRecord` automatically sets all the internal "changed" flags to true on the UpdatableRecord.  So then I tried this:

```
// orgPerson represents a POJO filled with my values to be inserted and null for everything else
// Note that orgPerson.orgPersonId is null
OrgPersonRecord orgPersonRecord = create.newRecord( ORG_PERSON, orgPerson );
orgPersonRecord.changed( ORG_PERSON.ORG_PERSON_ID, false );
orgPersonRecord.changed( ORG_PERSON.CREATED_TIME, false );
orgPersonRecord.insert()
Integer orgPersonId = orgPersonRecord.getOrgPersonId();
```

But that gives me the error `ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "pk_org_person"`.  And when I do this repeatedly, the values seem to keep increasing by 1.  This doesn't really make sense to me, but my greater question is: **Is there a good way I can do an INSERT based on my object values, or better yet, simply include only the non-null columns**?

I saw [JOOQ ignoring database columns with default values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18276421/jooq-ignoring-database-columns-with-default-values), but that doesn't seem to resolve this.  Any recommendations on the most concise way to handle this?

By the way, jOOQ has been fantastic to work with so far. Lukas, thank you for this awesome tool!

**UPDATE #1:**

The "not null issue" is addressed by Lukas's answer below, and that's an easy fix.

For the duplicate primary keys, I am definitely not confusing `INSERT` with `UPDATE`. When I run the above code (slight update since original post), jOOQ seems to arbitrarily pick a "starting" primary key value for `OrgPersonId`.  For example, when I first load up my environment, jOOQ might start with "11" for `OrgPersonId`.

Then, when I do an `INSERT`, jOOQ will attempt to supply a value of "11" for `OrgPersonId`, I'll get the `ERROR: duplicate key value` and the `INSERT` will fail.  If I then repeat the `INSERT`, jOOQ uses "12", then "13".  It succeeds or fails based on whether that ID is available, but it's not "starting" with the right ID.

The manual (http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.4/manual/sql-execution/crud-with-updatablerecords/identity-values/) says that `If you're using jOOQ's code generator, the above table will generate a org.jooq.UpdatableRecord with an IDENTITY column. This information is used by jOOQ internally, to update IDs after calling store()`.

**UPDATE #2:**

Ok, I just tried the generated query directly in Postgres and it fails there, too, with the same issue.  So, clearly this is a Postgres issue and not a jOOQ issue.  I'll post the final resolution on that when I find it in case anyone else runs into this.

**UPDATE #3:**

Issue has been resolved. We use FlywayDB (another awesome tool) to automate our database schema migration, and we had a bunch of `INSERT` statements in our Flyway scripts that manually INSERTED the id number.  This was convenient because we wanted to create a bunch of dummy data and wanted to guarantee the right foreign key relationships.

But manually specifying the primary key increment does not advance the Postgres sequence!  Hence, we had to cycle through the Postgres sequence before (correctly operating) jOOQ would get the right sequence value.

Solution is to remove all our manual inserts of the primary keys in our demo data migration scripts.

Comment: *"Lukas, thank you for this awesome tool!"*: You're welcome ;-) Just to be sure - there had been some fixed issues in this area, recently. Could you please indicate the jOOQ version you're using?

Comment: Sure, using jOOQ 3.4.2

Comment: OK, I'll be looking into it tomorrow

Comment: Thanks! BTW, just watched your GeeCon presentation; very nice coverage of evolution of Java + SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### violates not-null constraint

The first part that you're describing is a flaw ([#3582](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/3582)), which is related to a previous issue ([#2700](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2700)), which enforced storing `null` values loaded from POJOs into jOOQ `Records` for database columns that are `NOT NULL`. The fix will be in jOOQ 3.5.0, 3.4.3, 3.3.4, and 3.2.7

#### duplicate key value violates unique constraint "pk_org_person"

The second part probably is caused by the fact that you are really loading an existing record and then calling [`executeInsert()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#executeInsert-R-) on it (observe the `INSERT`, which will always execute an `INSERT` statement). You might want to call [`executeUpdate()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#executeUpdate-R-), instead

Comment: Thanks, Lukas. On the "not-null constraint", you're exactly right. That's an easy fix, either by manually setting the flags or copying your `resetChangedOnNotNull` method until 3.5.0 comes out.  The duplicate keys are still an issue. See next comment.

Comment: Regarding the duplicate keys, this is definitely not related to an accidental `INSERT` vs `UPDATE`. I've updated my original question (see UPDATE #1) with details of what I'm experiencing.  Either it's a bug, or I've misconfigured something.

Comment: Josh, jOOQ doesn't "pick ID values" for you. Only the database generates IDs, or you can do that yourself using a `RecordListener` or an `ExecuteListener`... I've just seen your UPDATE 3, so that explains the same thing. From a Stack Overflow point of view, this Q&A starts becoming a little confusing with the updates in your question :-) It's generally a good idea to ask only one question at a time and then not update the question with answers... But you can always answer your own question and accept that answer yourself.

Comment: Thanks, Lukas. I agree this post was getting confusing to follow; I'll keep it better organized in the future. :)